# How to develop a bot for a(n) (arbitrary) FPS game without a game API?

Tags: ai, first-person-shooter, bot

I've been interested in artificial intelligence in computer games for a long time. The question that I have been asking for a long time and to which I have not yet found an answer is the following: How to write a bot that can move through an FPS game without the game offering an API for developers? Is this possible by having only the information that the player sees on his screen? What options are there to implement something like this? Must the pixel information on the screen be processed by neural networks to operate object recognition (e.g., walls, doors, adversaries)? How can a bot, e.g. understand if he is running against a wall and is hanging on the wall? The bot would have to get a feedback about the fact that he just does not move forward in the world, because he hangs on the wall. So far I have not found an answer to these questions. For hints I would be very grateful, like also scientific articles.

**As a supplement:** The starting point for my question should be that you have no access to the source code of the game. Also, the game has no API through which the position data, environment data, etc. can be read.

Comment: Too incomplete for an answer, but: If the bot works on the system the game runs on, it should have access to whatever data is being transmitted to the GPU. That means it can know the worldspace vertex positions of all rendered triangles, allowing it to map the entire game world.

Comment: Are you trying to build such a bot? For which game, and to what end? Asking about the end goal you're trying to achieve can help focus answers on the aspects that are most relevant to what you need.

Comment: @Peethor Thanks for your comment. Can you give a little more detail to your statement? I think that this data is generally not easy to obtain, since the game developers are trying hard to encrypt the whole !?

Comment: @DMGregoryIt is not a specific game at the moment. I've recently seen first-person shooters like Apex Legends and CS: GO. But also third-person shooters, such as Fortnite Battle Royale by Epic Games. I'm just interested in whether there are methodologies that can be used to write bots for such games that can behave intelligently in the world.

Comment: Cipher data that goes to the GPU? not imposible... yet, that is dumb. It implies that your shader code has to decipher. That will kill performance like hell. There could be ways to inspect the process memory to find objects, if whatever anti-cheat solution they have lets you. Besides... can you record the screen? Currently there are aimbots that use computer vision on screen captures, and computer vision solutions are more accesible than ever (OpenCV, OpenPose, TensorFlow, etc...). Go learn computer vision.

Comment: @Theraot I am able to capture the screen. It is my own pc I am developing on. My question mainly aims at moving in the virtual world. I wonder how the bot can know (in real time) where he is at the moment and how he may be able to get to a specific position. I'm not interested in learning techniques that teach him how to behave intelligently, but mainly how he can get the input. So it's about the sensor data, to express it in words of AI. An Aimbot, on the other hand, still requires user input to move.

Comment: The techniques of computer vision allows you take the screen capture (one taken programatically) and extract useful information from there. For an aimbot, it could look for human shaped things, find their heads and that tells it where to aim. Of course, you do not have to stop there. Computer vision can be used to recognize objects in the worlds, for instance. If there is a minimap, you could take it from the sceen capture too. And so on. Yes, every game UI is diferent and you will have to work around that. And yes, usually you won't have the whole map available to you at once.

Comment: @Theraot And that is exactly my question: Do I have to map a level sufficiently with video recordings? Then do some form of feature extraction on the captured images to get an idea of the map, where there are doors, etc.? And while playing, run a neural network that recognizes previously seen areas and can give distances to objects, doors, opponents? Is there any scientific work on this topic?

Comment: I think you want [Robotic mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_mapping), in particular what you describe is similar to [SLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping). I have seen it used for augmented reality, but not for a bot. I do not think you need that in realtime, you could have the AI map the place and then have it hardcoded for future runs. Then the problem is finding where the avatar is at a given instant, and there are usually UI clues that help with that. -> [Active Neural Localization](https://sites.google.com/view/active-neural-localization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little surprised that no one has answered this, and I am no expert, but the high level concept for one approach, [detouring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Detours), is straightforward in concept! What your bot will do is read the graphics data, usually from the GPU, and then output keyboard and mouse mappings. You could simply use the screen as input [hard but doable] or you could use the graphics resources as input. As discussed in the machine learning paper "[Playing for Data](https://download.visinf.tu-darmstadt.de/data/from_games/data/eccv-2016-richter-playing_for_data.pdf)", the game communicates resources of different types, including geometric meshes, texture maps, and shaders to the gpu. The game then specifies how these resources should be combined to compose the scene. Because this is consistent between sessions, by tracking the application of resources to different scene elements, you can establish associations between these scene elements. You can intercept these communications with *detouring*, which is often used by screen capture software and graphics debugging and performance analysis tools. One such tool that is commonly used is [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/). By implementing a wrapper for DirectX and using RenderDoc to wrap Direct3D, you can then start monitoring the graphics communication elements. With those in hand, you can decide which virtual mouse and keyboard actions to take and when.

Why don't people do this more often you might ask? Some people do, but its a lot of work, and not guaranteed to yield results.

Comment: Son, that was excatly, what I was looking for. Thank you. The provided paper was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I should also mention, that if you end up developing a bot to play and win online games, this falls squarely within the "hacking" rules of most games and is usually strictly prohibited. Such a bot will most likely be booted.

Comment: I know. My interest is purely scientific.